# Best practice for updating @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs2

I am using the following and want to know what is the best practice to update them? Can I change one, @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest for example, and the rest update too?

`````
@types/jest": "^24.0.19" 
@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0", 
@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3````
`````

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to upgrade the dependencies all individually and ensure you're using versions that are compatible with one another. However, `vue-cli` is being replaced by `create-vue` so if you're planning to upgrade your app you may want to follow the migration guide created by the Vue devs and go with their recommendations.

[Here's the guide](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-vue-cli-to-vite/)

[And here's](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#project-scaffolding) what the Vue.js team is currently saying about `vue-cli`

> Vue CLI is the official webpack-based toolchain for Vue. It is now in maintenance mode and we recommend starting new projects with Vite unless you rely on specific webpack-only features. Vite will provide superior developer experience in most cases.